# loading a js file asynchronously from a js file that loads asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, loading

I had a javascript file(initial.js) on the page inserted through the script tag like so:

```
<script src="initial.js"></script>
```

This file creates dom elements(let say two links) and also loads another jQuery plugin(plugin.js) asynchronously via jQuery ajax method. Clicking on those two links brings up a module from the jQuery plugin(plugin.js).

The javascript file(initial.js) was then modified to load asynchronously on the page via jQuery ajax instead of via script tag. This has resulted in some events not getting attached to the links intermittently and this results in the plugin not being called.

I believe the browser is loading the async scripts in its own order and hence the links fail to launch the plugin intermittently. Any pointers to resolve this issue with this new set up?

Comment: If the plugin has been loaded aysnchronously from `initial.js` already, there should be no problems with load order. I guess it's the content of those scripts that matters - could you show them to us?

Answer (score 0):

At a high-level, I think you need to look into something like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/).  Alternatively, you could look into some jQuery event handling code which allows you to listen on load events of calls which may help you determine when one script loaded before loading the next one.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably tried something like this in the past:

```
var output;
$.get('data.php',function(data){
    output=data;
});
alert(output);
```

You will get an undefined error because Javascript doesn't wait around for the AJAX call to be returned before moving onto the next code.

Same thing goes for scripts.  If you place multiple calls to multiple scripts, you will probably get the smallest one returned the quickest, and that script executed. If you load a script that is 10kb and then one that is 1kb, the 1kb script will probably return the quickest and then be executed even though it was called after the 10kb script.

To correct this, you could make a queue system and then only load each script after the previous has loaded:

```
var scripts=['script1.js','script2.js','script3.js'];

$(document).ready(function(){
    loadScript();
});

function loadScript(){
    if(sendQueue.length==0)
        return;
    $.getScript(scripts[0],function(){
        scripts=scripts.slice(1);
        loadScript();
    });
}
```

But if you are loading scripts from within scripts from within scripts... very Inception like, then this still may not work.